# Why does Typescript throw an error when its return Type is its generic parameter?

Tags: typescript

Simple logic here:

```
type ToggleValues = "skills" | "people";

type Return<T extends ToggleValues> = { value: T };

const people1: Return<"people"> = { value: "people" };
const people2: Return<"people"> = { value: "people" };
const skills1: Return<"skills"> = { value: "skills" };

const searchTermCombinations = <T extends ToggleValues>(toggleValue: T): Return<T>[] => {
  switch (toggleValue) {
    case "people":
      return [people1, people2]; // is Return<"people">[]
    case "skills":
      return [skills1]; // is Return<"skills">[]
    default:
      throw new Error("ToggleValue not implemented");
  }
};
```

Both returns show an Error, that Return<"people" OR "skills"> aren't assignable to Return<T>. But when the method is called T is already either "people" or "skills" so I don't get why Typescript doesn't get it...

My goal here would be to return an Array of only either Return<"people"> or "skills".

The temporary fix here would be to cast both returns as Return<T> but then i would run into the issue that I'd have the possibility of an array with both "skills" and "people"

Edit:

a suitable workaround I found looks like this, but it feels like I'm doing Typescript's job here...

```
[…]
      const ret = [people1, people2] satisfies Return<"people">[];
      return ret as Return<T>[];
[…]
```

Comment: If you let the TS infer the return type of the function. You will find the return type is `Return<"people">[] | Return<"skills">[]`

Comment: hmm, intersting, so how would i have to write the return type for every future case of Return<T>?

Comment: ah I get it, just Return<ToggleValues> but then I'm at my initial point, I want Return<T> back^^

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't narrow generic types inferred from a function argument when the type of that argument is narrowed within the function. So within each of your cases, though you might know you've effectively narrowed the generic type of the function, TypeScript still thinks it could be the other type (or the full union, or `never`).

As far as I know, there's no perfect way to handle this. You could set up your function with overloads rather than using a generic, but this doesn't scale well if you need more than just these two potential values.

Alternately, you could use a type assertion. Yes, it is generally best to avoid type assertions as you're effectively opting out of type checking. But also, they are really the only way for you to tell the TypeScript compiler about things it doesn't know. Like in this case, that you've narrowed the type of `T`, so the value you're referring really is typed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm waiting a couple of days to see if someone else comes up with sth. If not, i mark you as the winner ;-)

Comment: If they do, please let me know since I'd like to know as well :)

Answer (score -1):

because the parameter `T` is undefined it doesn't know what `T` is so it throws an error because it doesn't know if `people1, people2...` has the correct type  `= people...` Are not